# How to get yml paramters outside the ActionController

Tags: symfony

- I have in my ActionContoller-Method : doSomeAction().
- This one in calling a new Class, eg. my DocumentManager, controlling my Documents.
- This DocumentManager needs the FileUploadManager.

ok  ...

- ActionContoller -> DocumentManager -> FileUploadManager

Now I need to get some parameters from my config file stored at: app/config/config.yml

- I want to use something like in Symfony 1.4 : sfConfig::get('myVar') ....
- I don't want to write for every paramter-pool a separate service  ....
- I cannot define all parameters as arguments for a Service ...
- Also I don't want to pass the actionController ( similar objects like the AppKernel ) through all classes I get in touch with ...

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use parser and dumper:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Dumper;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;


    private function readconfigFile(){
            $configFile = $baseUrl.'/config/config.yml';
            $yaml = new Parser();
            $configArray = $yaml->parse(file_get_contents($configFile));

            $readValue = $configArray['doctrine']['orm']['entity_managers'];

            return $readValue;

}
```